# Update GoogleTagManager Pod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, google-tag-manager

I have a working swift application with GoogleTagManager and Firebase/Analytics pods installed using Cocoapods.

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'GoogleTagManager', '~> 3.0'
```

My bridging header file imports the tag manager libraries:

```
#import <GoogleTagManager/TAGManager.h> <-- line that is causing the first error.
#import <GoogleTagManager/TAGContainer.h>
#import <GoogleTagManager/TAGContainerOpener.h>
#import <GoogleTagManager/TAGDataLayer.h>
#import <GoogleTagManager/TAGLogger.h>
```

Builds successfully and runs with no problems.

I am trying to update both the firebase and tag manager pods. modified the pod file as the following:

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '~> 5.1'
pod 'GoogleTagManager', '~> 7.1.1'
```

Then, I ran:
`pod update GoogleTagManager` and `pod update Firebase/Analytics`.

Suddenly now I have 2 compilation errors:

> 'GoogleTagManager/TAGManager.h' file not found
>
> failed to emit precompiled header '/blabla.pch' for bridging header '/blabla/Bridging-Header.h'

**I only updated the pods what would be the thing that caused the problem?**

Comment: It might also be worth posting this on GitHub as an issue for Firebase. The developers are good at answering questions on there or fixing bugs if it is a bigger issue

Comment: Likely something triggered/exposed by uprevving GoogleTagManager by 4 major versions.  I'd recommend seeing how 3.x and 7.x differ.

Comment: @hasan Did you resolve this issue - I'm having the same problem

Comment: I don’t fully remember. But, what I recall that I ended up with removing it and using another one. Something related to there is a new library.

Comment: @AshleyMills have you fixed that header issue, I am also facing same error after update the pod file, If you have already fixed, Could pls mention here what was the fix?